# need corrections in css image gallery

Tags: css

In the image gallery in the below page, how do i align the thumbnails of the image gallery to the center.
 http://kbay.in/details.php?id=5

I tried everything including aligning the tables and tds too...need help badly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

1) - Remove **align="center"** from the table data which is right above **div id="galleryVideo**"

`<td colspan="4" height="310" align="center" valign="middle">`

2) - Then to the ID Gallery add padding-left: 50px; or percentage which ever you prefer.

```
<div id="gallery" style="padding-left: 50px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that using a table for that sort of layout isn't optimal. You should reconsider creating it with div elements instead.

Here's a jsfiddle with an example layout: http://jsfiddle.net/J4bkm/10/